# Finding the lowest double in a Java array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to catch the lowest double from user input. I am only catching the value of the initialized min variable - what am I missing? Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[] lowNum = new double[10];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i=0; i<=9; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter a double: ");
        lowNum[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }
    input.close();
    double min = calcLowNum(lowNum);
    System.out.println(min);
}


public static double calcLowNum(double[] a) {
    double min=0;
    for (int i=0; i>=9; i++){
      for (int j=0; j>=9; j++){
          if (a[i]<=a[j] && j==9){
              min=a[i];
          }
          else {
              continue;
      }
    }
    }

    return min;
```

Comment: try to sort them with natural ordering in this case the smallest number is at first position and the biggest number is at last position

Comment: @anfy2002us: That's `O(n logn)` at best, whereas the minimum can easily be found in `O(n)`.

Comment: You don't appear to need an array at all. I would remember the lowest number inputted instead of remembering all the numbers.  BTW: By lowest to do mean closest to negative infinity?

Answer (score 4):

You could just use [Collections#min](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min(java.util.Collection)) to find the minimum value. You will need `Apache Commons-Lang` for this though.

```
// This would be the array 'a'
double[] array = {15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

// Convert the primitive array into a Class array
Double[] dArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(array);
List<Double> dList = Arrays.asList(dArray);

// Find the minimum value
Double returnvalue = Collections.min(dList);

return returnvalue; // or you can do returnvalue.doubleValue() if you really want
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, change the `i>=9` and `j>=9` to `i<=9` and `j<=9` in:

```
for (int i=0; i>=9; i++){
  for (int j=0; j>=9; j++){
```

Otherwise, your loops are effectively no-ops.

A far more robust approach is to write the loops like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
```

or like so:

```
for (double val : a) {
```

Finally, finding the minimum can be done by iterating over the array just once, comparing each element with the current minimum (but make sure to initialize `min` appropriately!)

Comment: Even more conventional `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {`.

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked my typos.

Answer (score 3):

If You really need to store all inputs and than find minimal, easiest way to do it to use library function for sorting array:

```
...
//sorting array, so first element will be the lowest
Arrays.sort(lownum);

double min = lownum[0];
```

I agree with Peter Lawree You don't actually need all the array; You need to save first input and all the followings compare with it and store if lower:

```
double lastInput=0, min=0;
for (int i=0; i<=9; i++) {
   System.out.println("Enter a double: "); 
   lastInput = input.nextDouble();
   if (0==i) {
       //if this is first iteration, save first input as min
       min=lastInput;
   } else {
       if (lastInput<min) min=lastInput;
   }
}
return min;
```

P.S. Actually, You should use Double.compare to compare doubles. So example with Arrays.sort() better if number of inputs not huge, in this case first example will take much more memory and time to execute.

**Update: Java8 solution**

```
double findMin(double[] input) {
 return Arrays.stream(input).min().getAsDouble();
}
```

Comment: `min = (i == 0 || lastInput < min) ? lastInput : min;`

Answer (score 0):

OMG, iterate over array - this is the worst workaround (but my bad english is more worse than it). Look at http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/ This lib contains **robust** code for your need (de-facto must have library in your project). You can see and analyze sources - it's free , but you experience in best practice will be grown as my english skills.
Below is excample of guava code:

```
  public static double min(double... array) {
    checkArgument(array.length > 0);
    double min = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
      min = Math.min(min, array[i]);
    }
    return min;
  }
```

P.S: learn libraries with standart code and do not reinvent the wheel. Be happy!

Comment: Thanks - I had to iterate as a learning process, but I like what you say. I want to be efficient. Thanks again.